# What is the MPL-value idiom ?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

I'm skimming through a [tutorial](http://www.slideshare.net/ysb33r/cronje-cconnections-practicalgenerativeprogramming#btnNext) on generative programming and I stumbled upon the **MPL-value idiom**:

```
template <int V>
class A
{
    A();
public:
    static const A<V> value;
};

template <int V>
static const A<V> A<V>::value;
```

What is it used for ? Can I have an example use case ?

Comment: `static const A<V> A<V>::value;`: `static` can not be used here.

Answer (score 1):

From your link:

> Preventing code bloat, only instantiate what is needed.

On slide 35 the presenter gives an example, where class A from the idiom corresponds to class Reportable.

Through this idiom he achieves that only classes are instantiated that are needed. Compare his previous example (slide 32) where he has to define an object of the class whether it will be used or not. This won't happen with the templated version.